# How to flex (or similar affect) when all child are absolute positioned

Tags: javascript, css, flexbox, css-position

Basically I've created a website that all the child elements of specific div are **must be absolute position**.

The purpose is every element that added (from dom - js)  will be part of one flex-row (flex-direction: row).
It seems like using `display: flex` on the container is impossible, because of the position of the children.

Any other possibilities ?
thanks.

js file, create dom divs inside main tag.

```
let newDiv = document.createElement("div");
  newDiv.classList.add("screen");
  newDiv.style.zIndex = zindex;
  zindex++; 
  document.getElementsByTagName("main")[0].appendChild(newDiv);
```

css, main = container.

```
main {
    /*Just in Case*/
    position: relative;
}

main>div {
    border: 5px solid black;
    width: 35vw;
    height: 60vh;
    cursor: move;
    position: absolute !important;
}
```

Comment: you cannot, but you can set the parent in absolute position instead, flex child need to see each other to get in position

Comment: @G-Cyr Hey, I didn't understand exactly what do you mean. I changed parent to absolute and what to do after that ?

Comment: ..  did you remove absolute from the children ? the bit of code you have shared is too short to show how and where those div are added , you do , have only one main tag , right ? ;)

Comment: I can't remove.Thanks anyway, probably I will need to create script for "my own flex".